# Mysterious memory leakage

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have code on the Internet which is not perfect written, however it seemed to me that there is no memory leakage. However to be sure I used valgrind who has different opinion.

Here is code:

```
class BaseClass {
public:
    virtual ~BaseClass() {}
};

class DerivedClass1 : public BaseClass {
};

class DerivedClass2 : public BaseClass {
};

class UserClass {
private:
    BaseClass* base_;
public:
    void setDerived(BaseClass* p_base) {
        delete base_;
        base_ = p_base;
    }

    UserClass (BaseClass *p_base){
        base_ = p_base;
    }

    ~UserClass() {
       delete base_;
    }
};

int main() {
    UserClass * my_class = new UserClass(new DerivedClass1);
    my_class->setDerived(new DerivedClass2);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is what valgrind says:

```
==10125== HEAP SUMMARY:
==10125==     in use at exit: 16 bytes in 2 blocks
==10125==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 1 frees, 24 bytes allocated
==10125== 
==10125== Searching for pointers to 2 not-freed blocks
==10125== Checked 179,544 bytes
==10125== 
==10125== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 1 of 2
==10125==    at 0x4C28C90: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==10125==    by 0x40074E: main (AbstractFactory.cpp:32)
==10125== 
==10125== 16 (8 direct, 8 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==10125==    at 0x4C28C90: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==10125==    by 0x400732: main (AbstractFactory.cpp:31)
==10125== 
==10125== LEAK SUMMARY:
==10125==    definitely lost: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
==10125==    indirectly lost: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
==10125==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10125==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10125==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10125== 
==10125== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 3 from 3)
--10125-- 
--10125-- used_suppression:      3 dl-hack3-cond-1 /usr/lib/valgrind/default.supp:1196
==10125== 
==10125== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 3 from 3)
```

For me everything seems right. In line 31 memory is allocated and during setDerived method it is deallocated.

Thank You for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is leaking, yes. And it's not a mystery either.

Really simple, you are never calling the destructor for `my_class`.

Add `delete my_class;` on the line just before `return 0;` in `main`.

Comment: The class may leak in other ways when used in future code since it doesn't follow the Rule of Three.

Comment: That's true, I know it is badly written. What's sad, that this code is published on site of my University I will do everything in order to change it. However I have found some samples of design pattern code on different websites, but maybe You can suggest best resources?

Comment: Sometimes EXAMPLES are simplified for the purpose of explaining a particular concept - it does mean that the example is not good for "copy and use", but it makes the example have less "code that doesn't actually help to explain the concept". For this reason, a lot of file-handling code omits the error handling, for example.

Comment: Ok I see this point. However I like this link very much: http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/10/patterns